# when will the 18.04.3 updates arrive to eos?

Tags: updates, kernel

Will the updates that come with 18.04.3 arrive eventually to eos? I know that I can install the enablement stack but I fear that it could break my eos install.

Comment: Second that. Could someone from elementary OS developers please explain, is it safe to manually install 18.04.3 upgrade to Juno, or the users are supposed to wait until it is officially integrated into elementary OS by the devs and is available in AppCenter?